# Finding the local maxima in a 2d array of nxn

Tags: algorithm, math, divide-and-conquer

In a 2d array of n×n, I am trying to find a number that's larger than its neighbour.
I approached this using the divide and conquer algorithm.

Next, I attempted to prove the correctness of my algorithm by exhibiting a suitable invariant i.e. I approached this by filling up 4x4 grid with random numbers, dividing it and finding the global maxima for each column selected (not sure this is the way to prove the correctness of the algorithm)

The bit I am most confused about is how to analyse the running time for my algorithm i.e. how many elements in the n×n array need to be visited in the worst case and finally if there is a way to show if the algorithm is asymptotically optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have better complexity than O(n^2), as you need to visit every element of an array. If you did not visit some element, it may turn out that your array does not have any local maxima except global maximum in the element you didn't visit. Brute force algorithm (just checking every element if it is a local maximum) is O(n^2), so there's not much space to do better or worse than that.

Re divide and conquer algorithm -- this seems to be overengineering for the given problem. You gain nothing by it, and you introduce additional complications (how do you handle borders between the parts?)